# is there any equal R language GDINA function in PHP?

Tags: php, r, math, statistics

I need to calculate some value using CDM GDINA method in php. I already try to study library GDINA at R programming language but i found it hard for me to understand because i never study statistic and it is very complex for me. is there any equal R language GDINA function in PHP?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Find pairs of nodes with two shared neighbors
B <- A %*% A
pairs_two <- which(B == 2, arr.ind=TRUE)
cat("Pairs with two shared neighbors:\n")
cat(paste(paste(pairs_two[,1], pairs_two[,2], sep=" - "), collapse="\n"))
cat("\n")

# Find pairs of nodes with three shared neighbors
pairs_three <- which(B == 3, arr.ind=TRUE)
cat("Pairs with three shared neighbors:\n")
cat(paste(paste(pairs_three[,1], pairs_three[,2], sep=" - "), collapse="\n"))
cat("\n")

# Compute Laplacian matrix
D <- diag(rowSums(A))
L <- D - A

# Check for isolated vertices
isolated <- sum(diag(D) == 0) > 0
cat("Isolated vertices present: ")
cat(ifelse(isolated, "TRUE", "FALSE"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).